# AS3 *** Security Sandbox Violation ***

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder, sandbox

I have faced this issue when I trying to load swf file from my application directory ?

What can i do to avoid that.....

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your swf in the browser, go to Global settings. In the last tab, add this SWF file as trusted. Reload the page once you are done.

Comment: I cant find this add this "SWF file as trusted".Is it possible to avoid at runtime or programatically?

Comment: Go to Global Settings >> Advanced >> Trusted Location Settings. Click on Add file and locate your SWF file locally.

Comment: Also, while embedding the swf file in your html file, use allowScriptAccess as always. I am guessing that you would have done this already. This Global settings change is only while testing your file locally. When you put it up on a site, it will work fine.

Comment: This is a desktop  application.Can i possible this at run time in as3?

Answer (score 0):

[Visit the Global Security Settings Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Then click **edit locations**, **add location**, **browse for folder** and select the drive containing your flash project.

Click **OK** and then select the radio button **always allow**.